# Using turtle.onscreenclick to find coordinates of a mouse click

Tags: python, python-3.4, turtle-graphics

I simply want to use the turtle method onscreenclick to find the coordinates of a mouse click. Currently, I have a grid on which I am playing Othello. I already have the algorithm to convert the raw coordinates to specific grid coordinates that can be interpreted by the game. I cannot seem to get the onscreenclick method working. On the docs, it says to use a 'fun' function with two arguments. I believe I have this, but it is not working. I am a beginner with python and turtle so any help would be appreciated :)

```
    import turtle

    xclick = 0
    yclick = 0

    def getcoordinates():
        turtle.onscreenclick(modifyglobalvariables())

    def modifyglobalvariables(rawx,rawy):
        global xclick
        global yclick
        xclick = int(rawx//1)
        yclick = int(rawy//1)
        print(xclick)
        print(yclick)

    getcoordinates()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got so close!

```
import turtle

xclick = 0
yclick = 0

def getcoordinates():
    turtle.onscreenclick(modifyglobalvariables) # Here's the change!

def modifyglobalvariables(rawx,rawy):
    global xclick
    global yclick
    xclick = int(rawx//1)
    yclick = int(rawy//1)
    print(xclick)
    print(yclick)

getcoordinates()
```

Catch the change? Syntactically, remove the parentheses after modfiyglobalvariables. **What you want is to pass the function, what you are doing is passing the output of the function.**

If you ran the code, you would get an exception (TypeError) saying you haven't passed the correct arguments; that's because it's trying to actually call modifyglobalvariables. Reduced, what you wanted was

```
bind_to_mouseclick( my_function )
```

In which case, at each mouse click, `my_function` will be called. At that point, it may or may not have the correct arguments supplied. Instead you said

```
bind_to_mouseclick( my_function() )
```

Python evaluates `my_function` and binds the *result of the call* to the mouse click. If `my_function` happens to return a function, that's great (maybe what we intended). If it returns an integer or a string, no good. The key is the exception, as noted above; if the function had required no arguments, this may have been subtler to detect

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

def get_mouse_click(x, y):   

   print(x, Y)

screen.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click)

screen.mailoop()
```